# React testing library - render is not showing all of the children

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, react-hook-form

Trying to write a test for my react-hook-form just so I can check if it has rendered properly. At the moment I'm failing at the first hurdle and can't get my form to render its children:

```
const props = {
  request: true,
  title: "testing title",
  commentPlaceholder: "Placeholder",
  tip: "helpful tip",
  submitButtonText: "submit",
  onSubmit: jest.fn(),
  recipientName: "User one",
  activeStep: 2,
};

it('Should render the CommentForm as if it was in the request flow', async () => {
  const { getByText, getByTestId, debug } = render(
    <CommentForm {...props} />
  );

  console.log(debug());
});
```

The console log outputs the below:

```
<body>
  <div>
    <form />
  </div>
</body>
```

Where as the component I'm testing has lots of children in it to create the form.

I've pinned pointed it to the wrapper that I am using in the component.

`<StyledForm onSubmit={onSubmit} schema={CommentSchema} onChange={handleChange}>`

If I change this to form then it renders all my children. This is a styled component that extends this method below:

```
const Form = ({ className, onSubmit, schema, defaultValues, children, mode, onChange, style }) => {
  const methods = useForm({
    defaultValues,
    validationSchema: schema,
    validateCriteriaMode: 'all',
    mode: mode || 'onSubmit',
  });
  const { handleSubmit, watch } = methods;
  const values = watch();

  useEffect(() => {
    onChange && onChange(values);
  }, [onChange, values]);

  return (
    <FormContext {...methods}>
      <form style={style} className={className} onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        {children}
      </form>
    </FormContext>
  );
};
```

I know that this is causing the problem but I can't understand why it wouldn't render the components. This is also the reason why when I change the `StyledForm` to a normal `form` element it works.

** UPDATE **

Now found out that it seems to be because I'm extending the styledComponent like so:

```
 export const StyledForm = styled(Form)`
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto 50px;
`;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
jest.mock('hoc/withForm', () => jest.fn(({ children }) => <form>{children}</form>));
```

This was the solution. I had to mock my HOC so that it returned a more basic element.